# How to get Spring oauth2 to accept content-type of application/json

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on a fairly simple spring boot API which will be secured by oauth2. All of the endpoints are working fine accepting applicaiton/json requests with the exception of the default spring /oauth/* endpoints which seem to require a requesting content-type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Is there any way to override this behavior or is there a library I need to be including in my spring boot application which will handle mapping? My pom.xml includes the following

```
<artifactId>oauth2-authserver</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>OAuth2 Auth Server</name>
<description>Authorization server for an OAuth2 controlled application</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security-oauth2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <wro4j.version>1.7.6</wro4j.version>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <spring-security-oauth2.version>2.0.7.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the OAuth2 spec

> Authorization Request
>
> The client constructs the request URI by adding the following
>      parameters to the query component of the authorization endpoint URI
>      using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

and

> Access Token Request
>
> The client makes a request to the token endpoint by adding the
>   following parameters using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format

Every request should use application/x-www-form-urlencoded